# is it possible to get specific documents based on a value inside list of maps in firebase cloud store in flutter app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

im trying to make a screen in my flutter app so each user(translator) can get the appointments assigned to him/her , the appointments are inside List of Maps in the clients documents as shown in the photo [Firestore document image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gST0.png)

here is my Appointment class

```
class Appointment {
  String date;
  String hospital;
  String translator;
  String translatorPhone;
  String driver;
  String driverPhone;
  String description;
  String doctor;
  String procedure;

  Appointment(
      {this.hospital,
      this.doctor,
      this.date,
      this.description,
      this.driver,
      this.translator,
      this.translatorPhone,
      this.driverPhone,
      this.procedure});
```

im able to get all the appointments as following

```
    StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseApi.getUserAppointments(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // print(' snapshot print ===  ${snapshot.data.docs}');
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          default:
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Something Went Wrong Try later');
            } else {
              //  final appointments =
              var documents = snapshot.data.docs
                  .map((e) => e.get('appointments'))
                  .toList();
              print('docs = ${documents}');
```

here is the printed result of all appointments:

> docs = [[{doctor: sabri, date: 20.08.2019, driver: farukk, translator:
> racha, translatorPhone: 333, description: desc123, driverPhone: 888,
> procedure: surgery22, hospital: medicalpark}], [{date: 20.5.2021,
> doctor: burak, driver: faruk, translator: ali, translatorPhone: 123,
> description: desc, driverPhone: 3214, procedure: surgery, hospital:
> medicana}, {doctor: burak222, date: 20.12.2021, driver: faruk222,
> translator: meral, translatorPhone: 555, description: desc222,
> driverPhone: 312, procedure: surgery222, hospital: medicana}]]

but im stuck between maps and lists while filtering the appointments according to the signed in user name

what i want to do is to show only appointments when the translator field value inside appointments array of type List<Map<String , dynamic >> is = current user

any help would be appreciated <3

Comment: Try serializing the response to dart objects, then filtering will be easier. `var filtered = apointments.where((e)=>e.translator == 'the translator you want').toList()`

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you data structure, but if `appointments` was a collection instead of an array, you could filter it easier.

Comment: @PeterKoltai yeah its also a valid option but i was trying to get all the info with the same read operation from database , i didnt want to read 2 documents everytime i want to get info. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

documents is a of type `List<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>`.

So do this:

```
// first we flatten the documents from List<List> to List.
List flat = documents.expand((i) => i).toList();
List appointments =
    flat.where((element) => element['translator'] == currentUser).toList();
print(appointments);
// TODO: Replace currentUser above with the user.
```

Or you can use this

```
List appointments = [];
for (var document in documents)
  for (var doc in document)
    if (doc['translator'] == currentUser) appointments.add(doc);
print(appointments);
```

But this is ineffective, you have to download all appointments whenever you need to get the appointments for a user. Rather, make appointments a collection, then call it like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('appointments')
    .where('translator', isEqualTo: currentUser);
```

Comment: im getting an error of " The method 'where' isn't defined for the type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' " 

and i wanted to get all the info by reading 1 document that is why im trying to do it this way , by creating a separate appointments collection i will need to read 2 documents 1 to get the patient info and the other to get the appointments.

Comment: Okay, yeah, you've not called data() yet. Replace 'documents[0].where(' with 'documents[0].data().where('

Comment: now i got a different error when running the app 

" Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'data'.
Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:9
Tried calling: data() "    

i guess i will make a new appointments collection to solve the mess :P

Comment: or Class 'List<dynamic>' has no instance method 'data'.
Receiver: Instance(length:1) of '_GrowableList'
Tried calling: data()

Comment: Sorry about that. I have corrected, tested and updated my answer. Please use it.

Comment: Glad I could help.